MS Graph API : C# Xunit test cases using IRequestAdapter in V5
I am looking for a solution to write xunit test cases for PostAsync using IRequestAdapter in V5.
Source Code :
public async Task AddGroupToAdministrativeUnit(Group group, AdministrativeUnit administrativeUnit)
{
var client = await _auth.GetGraphServiceClient();
await client.Directory.AdministrativeUnits[administrativeUnit.Id]
        .Members.Ref
        .PostAsync(new ReferenceCreate { OdataId = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{group.Id}" });

}
How can I write xunit test cases for this method? Not sure how to mock PostAsync? I am able to mock GetAsync following https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1843. Can someone help?
